# MongoDB C# setup and size limitations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

What's the procedure to set up a distributed MongoDB, and are there any size limitations specific to C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For distributed MongoDB you should read about [Sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding) which is a very nice feature of MongoDB. In short, Sharding offers:

- Automatic balancing for changes in
  load and data distribution
- Easy addition of new machines
- Scaling out to one thousand nodes
- No single points of failure
- Automatic failover

Comment: In support to Chris Heald answer above I'd like to share one impressive article I just read yesterday
Url: http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/02/28/notes-from-a-production-mongodb-deployment/

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's memory limits are due to the fact that it memory maps files. On a 32-bit system, you can't address a position in a memory mapped file which requires a number larger than 32 bits to represent.

- The maximum range of a 32-bit signed integer is 2^31-1 positions, or 2 gigabytes.
- The maximum range of a 64-bit signed integer is 2^63-1 positions, or ~9.2 exabytes (9.2 billion gigabytes).

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) "As of May 2009, the size of the World's total Digital content has been roughly estimated to be 500 billion gigabytes, or 500 exabytes." In practicality, you will hit hard drive space limits years before memory addressing limits are of concern. If you want to archive the entire internet on a single shard, you might have problems. :)

Comment: No, the 2GB limit does not apply to 64-bit systems for the reason I explained above.